# Animation is not coming out correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, animation, xcode6

I'm creating a menu that slides from the bottom and up via a UIButton that is pressed to activate the animation. But the animation is coming out incorrectly. It is supposed to work like this -https://youtu.be/79ZQDzzOHLk?t=2m52s (but in portrait mode) 
But here's how it works after I coded it:
[image]

And here's the codes for the animation in the viewcontroller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()


    @end

    @implementation ViewController
    @synthesize scrollView;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        draw1 = 0;
        scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 480, 55);
        [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(480, 55)];

        openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, 270, 60, 30);
    }
    - (IBAction)OpenMenu:(id)sender {
        if (draw1 ==0) {
            draw1 = 1;
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
            [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
            [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

            [UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.5];
            [UIButton setAnimationDelay:0.0];
            [UIButton setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

            scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 245, 568, 55);
            openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, 200, 60, 30);

            [self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollView];

            [UIView commitAnimations];
        } else {
            draw1 = 0;
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
            [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
            [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

            [UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.5];
            [UIButton setAnimationDelay:0.0];
            [UIButton setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

            scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 568, 55);
            openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, 270, 60, 30);

            [self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollView];

            [UIView commitAnimations];
        }
    }
    @end
```

How do I fix it so the UIButton comes at the bottom of the screen in portrait mode and it goes up and down like in the Youtube tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#define SCREEN_WIDTH ((([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) ? [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width : [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)

#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ((([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) ? [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height : [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize scrollView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    draw1 = 0;

    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT-55, SCREEN_WIDTH, 55);
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH, 55)];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(480, 55)];
}
- (IBAction)OpenMenu:(id)sender {
    if (CGAffineTransformIsIdentity(scrollView.transform)) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            scrollView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 55);
        }];
    } else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            scrollView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        }];
    }
}
@end
```

or, just change this method from what is above to the following (it's the same thing, just more elegant and simpler):

```
- (IBAction)OpenMenu:(id)sender
```

to this:

```
- (IBAction)OpenMenu:(id)sender {
      [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
      scrollView.transform = CGAffineTransformIsIdentity(scrollView.transform) ?
                             CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 100):CGAffineTransformIdentity;
     }];
}
```